# Set Youtube Video Thumnbail as Background Image Before Loading Video

Tags: html, css, video, youtube

I wonder if it is possible to see a Youtube Video Thumbnail before loading the video itself?

Here is an example of what I have at moment:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .video-background {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
      z-index: -99;
    }
    .video-foreground,
    .video-background iframe {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    @media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
      .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
    }
    @media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
      .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="video-background">
        <div class="video-foreground">
          <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PR97m89_s4c?controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=PR97m89_s4c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/jacksonjack/pen/VypELM

It loads the video but the first 2-3 seconds whilst it loads are a black screen.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a bit of JS code to prevent the loading time like 5 second and after show the video up... Add at that a fade while opening the loaded video and that's done :)